# Not getting all mails in Thunderbird

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird

I just added my account in Thunderbird in a new machine using POP3 that keeps my mail in my computer. But the problem is that I am not getting my mails which I have received earlier, it is only showing me mails which I received after adding my account in Thunderbird. When I did same in my laptop last year I was getting all message. Please resolve this problem.

Comment: Is this a gmail account you're accessing via POP3?

Comment: @philsf Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

In Mozilla, goto Tools>Import... and select Mail (or whatever else you require).

This is a feature of POP3. If you wish to co-ordinate emails from the past and maintain a common list, you need to select the imap sever for your chosen email account.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before asking this question but it always stops on second step giving me no next button. The page reads Import Wizard.

Comment: @Priyansh You may have a corrupted  popstate.dat file. Have a look at this Mozilla support thread https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/987918

Comment: No, I just checked. Everything is good.

Comment: @Priyansh then why not just use imap settings and resolve the issue more sensibly?

Comment: I already did that. But I still want to know the reason behind that.

Comment: @Priyansh One of life's mysteries... I doubt you will get an answer to that but good that you have seen the light and used the better imap facility.